# Show that the $p$ norm of $x$ is equal or less than one

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

So, I stumbled upon this exercise, in my set theory notebook and I had a lot of trouble finding some answers.

$$1\le p\le\infty$$

$$ \|u\|_p = \|v\|_p=1$$

Show that $\|x\|_p\le 1 \quad \forall x \in\{u+t(v-u)\mid 0\le t\le 1\} $

I tried starting from the definition of p norm and got into a lot of complex equations expanding the p norm of x and trying to substitute, but I feel there's a much easyer way, maybe something with Cauchy sequence?

PS: There may have been some poor latex in the formatting, apologies in advance.

Comment: So, what’s your question, exactly?

Comment: My bad, got messed up in the latex part and forgot to add the question, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just **Minkowski's inequality**, which states that

$$\|x +y\|_p \le \|x\|_p + \|y\|_p.$$

We see that for $x = u + t(v-u) = (1-t)u + tv, 0<t<1$,

$$\|x\|_p \le (1-t)\|u\|_p + t\|v\|_p = 1-t +t =1.$$

In particular this says that the unit ball in your vector space endowed with the $p$ norm (presumably $\ell^p$ or $L^p$) is **convex.**

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the triangle inequality of norm. In particular,
$$||x||_p = ||t v + (1-t)u||_p \le ||t v||_p + ||(1-t)u||_p = t + (1-t)=1.$$